# SEO-safe detect mobile user agent (iphone, htc, ...) and redirect to mobile version of website

Tags: redirect, mobile, seo

What's the best way to automatically detect mobile vs. full screen devices and redirect to mobile site automatically? I'm concerned about SEO so it is safe to do a detection with PHP and redirect to mobile version without unwillingly sending Google to that mobile version?

If PHP is ok, what are good libraries to use?

Answer (score 1):

It is good for usability to configure redirection to your mobile website.

The google webmaster blog has a very important topic on best practices for [mobile sites, concerning redirection and duplicate content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/running-desktop-and-mobile-versions-of.html)  (!!!)

In my opinioun, a very comprehensive and up-to-date database (including source code in multilple languages) is WURLF: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special libraries to do that. [`User-Agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user+agent+mobile) header will do the trick.